# RelativeLayout misbehaving

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Here I am with my app finished to at least 50% and I'm still having trouble with `RelativeLayout`. For some reason, `event_price` is where it should be but `event_organ` is not visible at all. If I set `marginBottom` to `event_price`, it doesn't work either, the `CardView` doesn't expand. RelativeLayout doesn't work as easily as I supposed...

I've got this layout which is the direct and only child of a `CardView`:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView> // pseudocode to show container
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/event_photo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:transitionName="eventImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/event_photo"
        android:text="Title"
        android:transitionName="eventTitle"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/event_title"
        android:text="Date"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Time"
        android:layout_below="@id/event_date"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_price"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="£ FREE" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_organ"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/event_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Screenshot:

[image: SS]

Comment: Silly question but have you checked to make sure you aren't changing the visibility in your Java code? Or put default text in it to see if it shows up in the editor before running?

Comment: Yes, I'm not changing visibility. I tried lots of attributes to position items and I had it visible at some point but never the way I wanted it, with this configuration it's not visible at all.

Comment: And I created a simple test layout with TextViews only, I tried to position them and it worked...so I applied the same logic to this one but it doesn't work...wow

Comment: hmmm but there is no relationship between event_price+event_organ and the rest of the views(beside parent) how would you want to mesure the parent height then ?

Comment: There is no `text` value in `event_organ`.  Works fine inside a linear or relativelayout once I added a text value.  @Selvin its not always necessary.  event_organ and event_price at laid out bottom-up.

Comment: I'm loading data from the internet (successfully), (for that field as well), so no need for a text property. As far as I know, there is no need to have relationship between ALL items. I tried adding layout_below="@id/event_time", still invisible. And btw I tried a simple use case with Relative Layout+Linear layout, items align correctly, but not in my real Use Case.

Comment: using common sens: parent's height is wrap_content ... there is no connection between something connected to it Top and Bottom of th parent... so wrap_content  = MAX(top_connected_views_height , Bottom_conected_views_height) ... but yes, it just a common sens

Comment: If I add ` android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to my event_organ, it's visible but it overlaps with event_price, even though there is below and above tags for example..

Comment: Try removing android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" in your event price and see if it still overlaps

Comment: I need it because I want event price to be at the bottom of it all... Guys I have one stupid fix for now. When I add this to event_organ: `android:layout_below="@id/event_photo"` and `android:layout_marginTop="25dp"`  it works fine. So instead of controlling the position of it relative to the event_price I just put it under the photo and I add the margin I want so that it appears above event_price...It's 'hacky' let's say because I suppose on different devices this margin would look different but... I don't know what's the issue

Comment: I added a screenshot for you to see what I want to achieve with "TrampsLTD" which is event_organ. I need to add a bit more margin for it to go nearer but that's why I didn't want to do it this way. I think using `below` or `above` would be the better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

In your

```
android:layout_below="@id/event_time"
```

in your event_organ TextView

Move event_organ xml code above event_price and remove the android:layout_above="@id/event_price".

In your event_price TextView add

```
android:layout_below="@id/event_organ"
```

Did it help? If not let me know

Comment: Try add a default text at your event_organ and see if that make it appear.